# crc32() vs hash() function differences

Tags: php, hash, comparison, collision, equality

I think that I don't understand the difference between these two functions
I was trying to find any relation between them by runing following code (PHP 5.6)

```
$crc_codding = crc32("codding");
$crc_gnu = crc32("gnu");

$hash_codding = hash("crc32", "codding");
$hash_gnu = hash("crc32", "gnu"); // hash collision with $crc_codding example

var_dump(hash_equals($hash_codding, $hash_gnu));  // bool(false)

var_dump($crc_codding==$hash_codding);            // bool(false)
var_dump($crc_codding==$crc_gnu);                 // bool(true)
var_dump($crc_codding===$crc_gnu);                // bool(true)
```

But this did not help me, does hash() funtion have some built-in salting mechanism?

I am not sure if I can tell something more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash() algo that corresponds to the crc32() function is actually 'crc32b' and not 'crc32'. Read the end of the warning on the PHP's manual of the [crc32](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) function.